# How to build custom sentences with OpenXML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I would like to know if there is a way to "play" with sentences in a .docx.

Here's what I need to do:

I have a paragraph in a document

exemple of my paragraph:
This is a paragraph that I need to format ***based on some conditions*** and I can't figure how to do this with openxml sdk.
end of exemple.

So based on a condition that I evaluate in c# I would like to add/remove the text. Another thing that you should know id that I would like the product owner to change the text of the document.

Basicly what I want to acheive is having a template document that my product owner can edit at will but in this document the text might change based on for whom the document is produce.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a template document in Word and create a **content control** in each place you want the text to be dynamically inserted. For each created content control, you should set unique **Tag** property value.

In your c# application code, you can then find a content control by its tag quite easily. After you find it, you can save its parent node, remove the content control and insert the text you want as a child paragraph element for the parent node saved earlier.

You can add content controls by using Developer tab. If you can't see it, you can use steps described here in order to show it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx .

Answer (score 0):

There are some complexities involved in replacing text because text can be broken into multiple runs. If you want your owner to be able to edit the document, this is a problem you must solve. Luckily, there is sample code that you can use as part of the [PowerTools for Open XML](http://powertools.codeplex.com). PowerTools were written as cmdlets for PowerShell, but you can take the core C# code for your own programs. The TextReplacer.cs module should give you a good starting point. You will need some of the other modules that it depends on, like PtOpenXmlDocument.cs, PtOpenXmlUtil.cs and PtUtil.cs. I hope that helps.