# OpenXML Generated Code freezing Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, openxml

I am working on for DocumentML processing for a client and I am completely new to OpenXML. I have read and listened to Erik White's blog and OpenXML seems pretty powerful. The issue that I am having is that the code generated by OpenXML Productivity tool has 21121 lines in it. I Added a class and pasted this code in there, now any time my solution tries to get into that class it freezes, also if I try to open the the class in the IDE, VS freezes. I have never had this issue before, as my machine has 8 GB of Ram and a 4 core processor.

Has anyone had this issue before? Is there a setting or something that needs to be done for OpenXML. I am running VS 2010 Ultimate SP1 and I did a full install. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT 1**

I am trying to access a checkbox that I have in my form. When I look at the derived XML, I see

```
<w:sdtPr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
 <w:rPr>
  <w:rFonts w:asciiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:hAnsiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:cstheme="minorHAnsi" />
  <w:sz w:val="20" />
  <w:szCs w:val="20" />
 </w:rPr>
 <w:id w:val="-210274200" />
 <w14:checkbox xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml">
  <w14:checked w14:val="0" />
  <w14:checkedState w14:val="2612" w14:font="MS Gothic" />
  <w14:uncheckedState w14:val="2610" w14:font="MS Gothic" />
 </w14:checkbox>
</w:sdtPr>
```

I am trying to check to see if the node contains a checkbox, so I do something like this.

```
  private static XNamespace w14 = 
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml>";

 if (element.Elements(w + "sdtPr")
                        .Elements(w14 + "checkbox").Count() > 0)
                { }
```

But the code never falls into that conditional. Is there something that I am missing here? 
Thanks for the help
**END EDIT 1**

Comment: It looks like a big file :). Why do you need to use the whole code generated by the productivity tool? If you want to create a document with partially dynamic data, I would recommend creating a template document with some content controls and just fill the places you want data to be inserted dynamically. I wrote about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891781/how-to-build-custom-sentences-with-openxml/7905155#7905155. If it's applicable in your case and you need help with this, let me know.

Comment: @LukaszM thanks for the offering for help, I have them as all Content Controls, but am having problems replacing the data with data from my custom object. I would appreciate the help if you have time.

Comment: So, please edit your question and give some details what issue you have with replacing the content controls and what kind of data you want to insert there.

Comment: Hi, actually, I'd like to back up a bit and have you explain your higher level scenario. What is your overall goal? Sometimes using the code that the productivity tool generates is not the correct approach. Often, a better approach is to use a template document, modify the template document, and then save the newly 'generated' document. If you can explain your scenario, then maybe I can suggest the correct architecture that you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

We initially did the same approach by copying the code generated by the productivity tool and using it as a file. This caused VS to crash all the time and it was very tedious to test and update since each change required a complete regeneration of the code. This pushed us to use templates, which has saved us a ton of time and is pretty easy to load into memory and then manipulate with the Open XML SDK:

```
byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\temp\\test.docx");
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    stream.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
    {
       // Do work here
    }
    File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\temp\\test.docx", stream.ToArray()); 
}
```